# How can I calculate the probability of drawing a certain card as I repeatedly draw new hands?

Tags: probability

In a trading card game I am playing, the following rules apply:

- The deck consists of N cards total.
- Among these N cards are X identical copies of a particular card I wish to calculate the probability of drawing.
- I initially draw 7 cards. If I wish, I may shuffle these 7 cards back into the deck and draw 6 new cards. I can repeat this any number of times, each time drawing 1 card less.

Given N and X, how can I calculate the probability of drawing this particular card as a function of the number of times I redraw?

To be clear, I wish to know the probability that one of the hands I drew would have contained this card, as I continue to redraw. So the probability should go up with each successive draw. I do *not* mean the probability that the hand I decide to keep has it, in which case each successive smaller hand would have a lower probability of containing the card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Doug tried to begin., we may assume that every card in the deck is labeled.

There are $\binom{n}{7}$ ways to pick a hand of seven cards.  There are $\binom{n-x}{7}$ ways to pick seven cards where none of which are the desired card-type.

Since every hand is equally likely, we apply the definition of probability in an equiprobable sample space, $Pr(E)=\frac{|E|}{|S|}$ to find the probability of *not* drawing a desired card in the first hand as $\dfrac{\binom{n-x}{7}}{\binom{n}{7}}$

Applying the multiplication principle of probability, if we were to continue to not draw our desired card, we would have a probability of:

$\dfrac{\binom{n-x}{7}}{\binom{n}{7}}\dfrac{\binom{n-x}{6}}{\binom{n}{6}}\dfrac{\binom{n-x}{5}}{\binom{n}{5}}\dfrac{\binom{n-x}{4}}{\binom{n}{4}}\dfrac{\binom{n-x}{3}}{\binom{n}{3}}\dfrac{\binom{n-x}{2}}{\binom{n}{2}}\dfrac{\binom{n-x}{1}}{\binom{n}{1}}$

The probability of having drawn at least one of the desired card types is then the opposite of the probability we found and will be one minus the probability found above.

---

*as an aside, the notation $\binom{n}{r}$ is the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) as mentioned previously in the comments*

Comment: Well explained, makes a lot of sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your chance of getting your card at least once is 1 minus the chance of getting skunked.  (skunked - getting none of the cards you hope to draw)
Your chance of getting skunked in the first draw. 
$\dfrac{n-x\choose7}{n\choose7}$

Your chance of getting repeatedly skunked

$\dfrac{n-x\choose7}{n\choose7}
\dfrac{n-x\choose6}{n\choose6}
\dfrac{n-x\choose5}{n\choose5}\dfrac{n-x\choose4}{n\choose4}\dfrac{n-x\choose3}{n\choose3}\dfrac{n-x\choose2}{n\choose2}\dfrac{n-x}{n}$

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with the notation you're using inside the parens. Could you tell me what it's called so I can look it up? Also not familiar with "skunked."

Comment: @Aerovistae $\binom{n}{r}$ is the notation for the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient), also sometimes seen: $\binom{n}{r}=~_nC_r=C(n,r)=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$.  It is the number of ways of choosing $r$ objects out of $n$ distinct objects available.

Comment: But then, Doug M wrote $\dfrac{x-n\choose7}{x\choose7}$ . . . if I understand you right, and there are `N=60` total cards and `X=4` of the card I wish to draw, isn't he saying we're picking `7` out of `-56` ?

Comment: @Doug check the way that you've written each.  Should it not instead be $\dfrac{\binom{n-x}{7}}{\binom{n}{7}}$ for the probability of being skunked on the first draw and $\dfrac{\binom{n-x}{8-i}}{\binom{n}{8-i}}$ in general for the $i$'th draw?

Comment: I think he mixed up which letter represented the total number of cards and which letter represented the number of those cards which are desirable.  @Aerovistae

Comment: I mixed up my n's and my x's... I will edit the post.